# How to inject a logger into an object during deserialization via a constructor parameter

Tags: c#, .net-core, json.net

I'm using dotnet core 3.1.

I have an class for which I want to be **sure** a custom logger property has been set, so I add this to the constructor:

```
class ConsolidatedPortfolio
{
    public ConsolidatedPortfolio(StructuredLogger sl)
    {
        Sl = sl;
    }
    
    public StructuredLogger Sl { get; }
}
```

In the code that creates a `ConsolidatedPortfolio`, how do I pass my `StructuredLogger` object to the constructor when using Newtonsoft.Json to deserialize?

The following line gives me an object with data correctly populated from the JSON but obviously its `Sl` property is null.

```
var consolPortf = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ConsolidatedPortfolio>(consolPortJson);
```

I want to be able to request deserialization and provide a `StructuredLogger` object to be set on the newly created `ConsolidatedPortfolio` object.

Note that `consolPortJson` doesn't relate to `StructuredLogger`. The JSON string contains info about a consolidated portfolio: name, value etc. `StructuredLogger` is a type that contains an `ILogger`. It has a `LogInfo` method that means stuff gets logged in a consistent way. I realise that I could change the `StructuredLogger` property on the `ConsolidatedPortfolio` to include a `set` and assign it after deserialization but wondered if its possible to make use of the constructor parameter during deserialization.

Comment: Just to be clear, does `consolPortJson` contain some information that's meant to represent the `StructuredLogger`? What does the JSON look like? It would be easier to help you with a [mcve]. (It's slightly odd as `StructuredLogger` sounds more like a *service* than *data*; my experience is typically representing purely data aspects as JSON...)

Comment: consolPortJson doesn't relate to StructuredLogger. The json string contains info about a consolidated portfolio; name, value etc. StructuredLogger is a type that contains an ILogger. It has a LogInfo method that means stuff gets logged in a consistent way. I realise that I could change the StructuredLogger property on the ConsolidatedPortfolio to include a Set and assign it after deserialization but wondered if its possible to make use of the constructor param during deserialization

Comment: I don't see how, without potentially creating a custom JsonConverter that knows the StructuredLogger to use. I could consider separating the two out: create a class that's *just* for serialization, then a separate class for "real" use, with a constructor in that that takes the serialization instance and the `StructuredLogger`. I've found that trying to keep types for serialization separate from everything else has served me very well in the past. It does involve a fair amount of duplication, but it adds a lot of flexibility.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To inject a logger into the `ConsolidatedPortfolio` object during deserialization you will need to create a custom `JsonConverter` class for it:

```
class ConsolidatedPortfolioConverter : CustomCreationConverter<ConsolidatedPortfolio>
{
    private StructuredLogger StructuredLogger { get; set; }

    public ConsolidatedPortfolioConverter(StructuredLogger sl)
    {
        StructuredLogger = sl;
    }

    public override ConsolidatedPortfolio Create(Type objectType)
    {
        return new ConsolidatedPortfolio(StructuredLogger);
    }
}
```

When you want to deserialize, construct the converter with the logger you want to use, then pass the converter to the `DeserializeObject` method:

```
var converter = new ConsolidatedPortfolioConverter(structuredLogger);
var consolPortf = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ConsolidatedPortfolio>(consolPortJson, converter);
```

Here is a working demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/OT324B

Comment: Congratulations, @BrianRogers, on hitting 100K reputation points in the very near future. Count me as the first to extend these warm words. As a fellow Chicago-area resident named Brian, I'd like to offer to follow the warm words up with a cold beer, if you're ever near Wheaton.

Comment: 99,966... I could go upvote your stuff for a few minutes and that'd be that. But I think we'll just wake up tomorrow and see you over the line in a more legitimate fashion. :)